# Merging Two Derived Tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Through the following SQL query, I am getting the table below

```
SELECT COUNT(Specialist_Category.Specialist_ID), Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name 
FROM Specialist_Category, Specialist_Category_Name 
WHERE Specialist_Category.Category_ID = Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_ID 
GROUP BY Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name 

+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| COUNT(Specialist_Category.Specialist_ID) | Specialist_Category_Name |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 3                                        | Mouse                    |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2                                        | Network                  |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2                                        | Keyboard                 |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I am also getting the following table using the query below

```
SELECT COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID), Problem_Category.Category_Name 
FROM Problem, Problem_Category 
WHERE Problem.Category_ID = Problem_Category.Category_ID 
GROUP BY Problem_Category.Category_Name 

+---------------------------+---------------+
| COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID) | Category_Name |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| 3                         | Keyboard      |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| 1                         | Mouse         |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| 1                         | Network       |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| 2                         | Printer       |
+---------------------------+---------------+
```

I am trying to build a query that would merge the two tables on the Speciality_Category_Name =  Category_Name, meaning that Categories appearing in the `Category_Name` but not in `Specialist_Category_Name` wouldn't merge into the new table.

I.e. the expected result is

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| COUNT(Specialist_Category.Specialist_ID) | Specialist_Category_Name | COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID) |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| 3                                        | Mouse                    | 1                         |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| 2                                        | Network                  | 1                         |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| 2                                        | Keyboard                 | 3                         |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
```

I have tried some queries using outer join, inner joins, unions, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I have tried

```
(SELECT COUNT(Specialist_Category.Specialist_ID), Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name, COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID)
FROM Specialist_Category, Specialist_Category_Name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID), Problem_Category.Category_Name 
    FROM Problem, Problem_Category 
    WHERE Problem.Category_ID = Problem_Category.Category_ID 
    GROUP BY Problem_Category.Category_Name) 
WHERE Specialist_Category.Category_ID = Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_ID 
GROUP BY Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name )
```

AND

```
(SELECT COUNT(Specialist_Category.Specialist_ID), Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name
FROM Specialist_Category, Specialist_Category_Name
WHERE Specialist_Category.Category_ID = Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_ID 
GROUP BY Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name ) 

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID), Problem_Category.Category_Name 
FROM Problem, Problem_Category 
WHERE Problem.Category_ID = Problem_Category.Category_ID 
GROUP BY Problem_Category.Category_Name) 

ON Problem_Category.Category_Name = Problem_Category.Category_Name
```

***EDIT:***

I got very close to the result using. However, I'm still not sure as to how I can select only `Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name` and not `Problem.Category_Name` instead of using * at the very start of the query

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT COUNT(Specialist_Category.Specialist_ID), Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name 
FROM Specialist_Category, Specialist_Category_Name 
WHERE Specialist_Category.Category_ID = Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_ID 
GROUP BY Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name ) 
t1 INNER JOIN 
( SELECT COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID), Problem_Category.Category_Name 
FROM Problem, Problem_Category 
WHERE Problem.Category_ID = Problem_Category.Category_ID 
GROUP BY Problem_Category.Category_Name ) 
t2 ON t1.Specialist_Category_Name = t2.Category_Name
```

Comment: `ON Problem_Category.Category_Name = Problem_Category.Category_Name ` is wrong you are using the same tables twice there `ON Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name = Problem_Category.Category_Name`

Comment: Thank you for noticing. Please see my edit. The query should now be correct .

Comment: "I'm still not sure as to how I can select only Specialist_Category_Name.Specialist_Category_Name and not Problem.Category_Name instead of using * at the very start of the query" use the t1 and t2 aliases.. `SELECT t1.*` ...

Comment: The issue is selecting the column from t2. `SELECT t1.*, t2.COUNT(Problem.Problem_ID) ` throws an error. COUNT(...) is the name of the column I want to retrieve from t2.

Comment: alias the COUNT functions `COUNT(Specialist_Category.Specialist_ID) AS name`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you